# KafkaStreams How to specify Serdes in stream aggregation?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a Kafka streams application and I have some trouble figuring out how to make an aggregation work.

I have a KStream `bankTransactions` where the keys are of type `String` and the values of type `JsonNode` so I configured my app's Serdes with

```
// Definition of the different Serdes used in the streams
final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = new JsonSerde();
final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();

config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, stringSerde.getClass().getName());
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, jsonSerde.getClass().getName());
```

I want to aggregate the values in a `KTable<String, Long>` where the keys will be the same but the values will be `Long`s extracted from my Json.

So firstly I wrote:

```
KTable<String, Long> totalBalances = bankTransactions
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
                () -> 0L,
                (key, transaction, balance) -> (Long)((Long)balance + transaction.get("amount").asLong()),
                Materialized.as("bank-total-balance")
        );
```

And I get the following error at runtime:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException:
A serializer (value: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer) is not compatible to
the actual value type (value type: java.lang.Long).
Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

I understand that Kafka is complaining because I'm trying to use the default Json serdes to serialize a `Long`. So reading from [confluent's doc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating) I tried this

```
KTable<String, Long> totalBalances = bankTransactions
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
                () -> 0L,
                (key, transaction, balance) -> (Long)((Long)balance + transaction.get("amount").asLong()),
                Materialized.as("bank-total-balance").withValueSerde(Serdes.Long())
        );
```

But then I get an error at compilation:

```
Error:(121, 89) java: incompatible types:
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.Long> cannot be converted
to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.Object>
```

I tried different way to write this code (e.g. using `Serdes.long()` instead of my `longSerdes`, trying to parametrize the types of `Materialize` and even trying to write my initializer and aggregator as function, Java 7 style) but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

So my question is simple: How to I properly specify the Serdes that `aggregate` should use when they are not the defaults Serdes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like the correct syntax is the following:

```
KTable<String, Long> totalBalances = bankTransactions
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
                () -> 0L,
                (key, transaction, balance) -> (Long)((Long)balance + transaction.get("amount").asLong()),
                Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("bank-total-balances")
                        .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
                        .withValueSerde(longSerde)
        );
```

The three types after `Materialize.` are the ones of the key, of the value and the one of the store used to materialized the KTable and this one shouldn't change. Then we can define the Serdes used to write in this key value store.

**Note** I got this syntax from a random repo found on github, I would still gladly accept an answer with a more precise answer backed by some documentation.

Comment: Using Java8 you would not need to specify the generic types. In Java7, if the type in unknown and Object is assume for the value and thus the case fails. It's not specific to KafkaStreams but some Java magic. Check out the example repo and check out the Java7 examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for pointing that out, I'll take a look at the examples

Comment: I think that (as @MatthiasJ.Sax said), the code can be written like this: 'Materialized.as("bank-total-balances").with(stringSerde,longSerde)'. So generics are not required any more.

Comment: @ClaudioTasso I don't work with Kafka anymore and don't really have time to update the answer to something more up to date, but feel free to add another answer (or to edit mine if it's less trouble for you)